# How can I disable the auto submit on a number EditText view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-edittext

I developed an App with a settings page.
I have a mix of `checkboxes`, `spinners` and `edittext` views inside a `gridlayout`.

Now I have the problem, that on the `edittexts` with the `inputtype="number"`, the user can press next/enter and the entire settings activity closes, which I don't want! (And btw produces some very strange behavior in my App, where neither `OnCreate` nor `OnResume` is called on a restart off the settings activity?!)

My xml looks like this:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="3"
    android:id="@+id/Settings_UndoTimer_TextArea"
    android:textSize="@dimen/double_text_size"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:gravity="end" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Settings_UndoTimer"
    android:id="@+id/Settings_UndoTimer_Label"
    android:textSize="@dimen/double_text_size"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:labelFor="@id/Settings_UndoTimer_TextArea" />
```

For each of the `edittext` views.

I already tried changing the `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` to `actionNone` and some others, but it still auto closes my activity on Enter...

Also it is only on the `inputType="number"` views, the other ones work like normal and skip to the next view on enter!

I really hope someone can help me on this, because I tried for hours and cant understand why it reacts that way.

EDIT:
After trying out the given answers, I still didn't get the results I needed.
But I found a small bug in my handling of the `edittext` fields with `inputType="number"`: I used `Integer.getInteger` instead of `Integer.parseInt`. This lead to a null-pointer-exception which in turn crashed the activity.
So it wasn't the enter function, but in fact the leaving of the `edittext`, that caused the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you try this below implementation. If this does not work, then paste your full xml here. We will be able to help you better.

```
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/yourItemId1"  
android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/yourItemId2"    
android:nextFocusRight="@+id/yourItemId3"    
android:nextFocusUp="@+id/yourItemId4"
```

Make these changes in your xml, only particular to the views that are not working as per your need.This basically says, on which view to move when focus is changed from the current one. Try this once.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Didn't help me with the question, but helped me organize my settings for the user, so cheers for the answer :).

Comment: @M.Horn, kindly accept and upvote if this helped. thank u.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:imeOptions="EMPTY" />
```

You have more info [here](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html?hl=es)

Comment: There is no imeOptions="EMPTY"... just returns an error upon build.